# Kibana 4.5 run as service on CentOS 7

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

What is the proper way to run Kibana 4.5 as service on CentOS 7?
When I run it as `./kibana`, I can conenct to it form another machine without any problem. When I run it with `systemctl start kibana` and check with `ps -ef | grep '.*node/bin/node.*src/cli'`it looks like running but refuses to connect. And goes down. What can be the  problem? Thanks in advance.

Here is content of kibana.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=no description given

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kibana
Group=root
Environment=CONFIG_PATH=/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
ExecStart=/opt/kibana/bin/kibana
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that much of a linux expert but i recently installed kibana using yum (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/setup.html#kibana-yum) on a minimal installation of CentOS 7 and did not face any issues whatsoever.

In order to have some debug logs and find out what is wrong in your case, edit the kibana configurations file

```
/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

and set a filename for the logging.dest property.

```
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana.log
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Igor,

I noticed a few questions you posted on Kafka so sounds like you need to set up a cluster that can ingest data and pass to Elastic. Kibana would be just user interface.

In my experience, components like ELK, Kafka, Zookeeper, etc should be managed by a watchdog process. I highly recommend looking at something like supervisord. http://supervisord.org/
You should run it as a service and the rest managed by the supervisor. It will guarantee starting components at boot but whats more important restart in case of failure and collecting logs. In case of Kibana, it is a NodeJS app that writes to stdout/stderr so to know what fails, you need to collect them.